# Amazon EC2 - Can I 'associate' a kernel (aki) with a specific AMI?

Tags: amazon-ec2, kernel, ec2-ami

I am making my own AMIs (Virtual machines on Amazon's EC2). I can't use the default kernel. I have to use one of the other provided amazon kernels. I am trying to make this AMI be really really easy to use and make sure an idiot can start it up. However there is the important step where they have to choose this kernel. Is there anyway to 'associate' a kernel with an AMI? I'd like if, when someone is launching this AMI, that kernel is automatically and always the selected choice in the 'Choose your kernel' select box. This way, someone can just click Next, next, next etc. to start it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can. From the [docs](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=1345):

> In addition to specifying an AKI at
>   launch time, you can create new AMIs
>   that launch with a specified AKI by
>   default. You can either rebundle an
>   existing instance that was bundled
>   with the desired AKI (as described
>   above) or you can provide optional
>   arguments to the ec2-bundle-vol
>   command.